# Calling the value of a variable from a variable value

Tags: powershell

I run a script in powershell

```
./name -i tom
```

then i want to call the value of a variable called $Tom from the input reference value of $i

```
$tom = 29 
$andrew = 99
$bill = 5

Echo $i's age is $i
```

This would print:

```
toms age is 29
```

Answer (score 0):

In powershell this would look like this:
Contents of `name.ps1`:

```
$person = $args
$ages = @{"Tom" = 23;
  "Andrew" = 99;
  "Bill" = 5}

$age = $ages[$person]

Write-Host "$person's age is $age"
```

And you would call it like this

```
.\name.ps1 "tom"
```

`$args`contains all the arguments that you send to the script. So if you call the script like this: `.\name.ps1 "tom" "bill"`, your result would be: `tom bill's age is 23 5`

Comment: is $args specific to picking up a value from .\name.ps1 "tom"

Comment: `$args` is a special value for the parameters you called the script/function with.

If you call it like: `.\name.ps1 "tom"`, `$args` contains `"tom"`.

If you call it with multiple values `.\name.ps1 "tom" "jerry"`,  `$args` contains an array with `"tom"` and `"jerry"`

Answer (score 0):

I would use hashtable, but if you have global variables, you can use following:

```
#variables
$tom = 29 
$andrew = 99
$bill = 5

#your parameter
$i = "tom"

#echo
Echo "$i's age is $((Get-Variable | ? {$_.Name -eq $i}).Value)"
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternative approach to those provided. More code, arguably overkill, but I think it's good to get a handle on PowerShell's [param](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj554301.aspx) feature.

```
# PowerShell's native argument/parameter support
param(
    [string]$name
)

# Create an array with Name and Age properties as hashtable.
$people = @(
            @{ Name = "Tom"    ; Age = 29},
            @{ Name = "Andrew" ; Age = 99},
            @{ Name = "Bill"   ; Age = 5}
            )

# Find the person by comparing the argument to what is in your array
$person = $people | Where-Object {$_.Name -eq $name}

# Single name version: If the person is found, print what you would like. Otherwise let the user know name not found
if($person -ne $null){
    Write-Host "$($person.Name) is $($person.Age) years old"
}else{
    Write-Host "$name not found in list."
}

<# Multiple name version : get rid of the param section

foreach ($name in $args){
    $person = $people | Where-Object {$_.Name -eq $name}
    if($person -ne $null){
        Write-Host "$($person.Name) is $($person.Age) years old"
    }else{
        Write-Host "$name not found in list."
    }
}
#>
```